# How can i open SISX package?

Tags: software-recommendation

I recently downloaded a dictionary and a movie both in a compressed format carrying the name (SISX), but my ubuntu 13.10 could not open it, i searched the software center but it did not hep.

Answer (score 0):

The SISX files are used by applications that are installed on the Nokia phones that operate on the Symbain operating system.   To try to open the file take a look at [S60 Software Suite](http://series60-remote.sourceforge.net/index.php?module=Content&func=view&pid=7&lang=en).

I don't have a Nokia phone to be able to test with, so I can't verify for sure that it will work.